# Angular Incorrect use of label with form elements

Tags: angular, typescript

error : Incorrect use of  from below code i was getting The label for attribute doesn't match any element id .This might prevent the browser from correctly auto filling form and accessibility tools

The code once again will post  here once it saved because  initially it's not allowing save the exact code

```
<mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">>
  <div class="formgroup">
  <ng-container matColumnDef="file">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Files </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element; let index=index " [formGroupName]="pageIndex*pageSize +index >
     
      <select id="file-{{index}}" class="form-select-ms" formControlName="file" [(ngModel)]="element.file">
        <option *ngFor="let food of foods" [value]="food.value">
          {{food.viewValue}}
        <option>
      </select>
 
    </mat-cell>
  </ng-container>
   <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Names </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element; let index=index " [formGroupName]="pageIndex*pageSize +index >
      
      <select id="name-{{index}}" class="form-select-ms" formControlName="name" [(ngModel)]="element.name">
        <option *ngFor="let id of grap" [value]="id.value">
          {{id.viewValue}}
        </option>
      </select>

    </mat-cell>
  </ng-container>
  </div>

  <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
  <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; let i=index; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
</mat-table>
<mat-paginator  [pageSize]="pageSize" [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 20]" showFirstLastButtons></mat-paginator>
```

pageSize=10;

pageIndex is by default zero based on items per page displayed list of items

Comment: The template you provided has several significant errors such as `[formGroupName]="pageIndex*pageSize +index >` not having a closing quote.  Fix your template

Comment: Sorry i forgot to mention [formGroupName]="pageIndex*pageSize +index" > in above code Even it has closing quote ,im facing same error Can you help me